# bazel c++ create and link with shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, bazel

I will base my question on **stage 2** from the [bazel tutorial for c++](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html).

Normally this example will create *hello-world* linked **statically** with *libhello-greet.a*. However I would like to create *hello-world* linked **dynamically** with *libhello-greet.so*.

Therefore I found some kind of workaround by using this **BUILD** file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libhello-greet.so",
    srcs = ["hello-greet.cc", "hello-greet.h"],
    linkshared = 1,
)

cc_import(
    name = "libhello-greet",
    shared_library = "libhello-greet.so",
    hdrs = ["hello-greet.h"],
)   

cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [
        ":libhello-greet",
    ],
)
```

but this doesn't feel like the best solution. Is there a better way to create and link with a **shared** library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the [`linkstatic`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.linkstatic)-flag in the binary, it will link all libraries either as static or as shared libraries. But I do not know how to link only certain libraries as shared libraries.

```
cc_library(
    name = "hello-greet",
    srcs = ["hello_greet.cc"],
    hdrs = ["hello_greet.h"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [
        ":hello-greet",
    ],
    linkstatic=False,
)
```